# Coloring the last frame in motion tween

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

So as it says in the title I'm creating a motion tween animation and my task is to change the color of the object in the last frame. Every time I try to do that color of my object changes in every frame. Does anyone have experience with something like this? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using motion tween, use motion editor, color effect

(Window -> Motion Editor, add a color effect - for example Tint)

Add there a keyframe just before the last frame

set the tint amount to 0% on the first frame and the added frame

and set the tint amount to 100% on the last frame

I think motion editor was added just in CS6